# How can I convert form data with multiple sections to json

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to save data in html form as json. But only my last row is saved. The reason for this is probably because the names of the inputs in the two sections are the same.

But I want the json file like this:

> {"name":"Name1","surname":"Surname1","gender":"f","birthDay":"15","birthMonth":"1","birthYear":"1995"},
> {"name":"Name2","surname":"Surname2","gender":"m","birthDay":"20","birthMonth":"2","birthYear":"2020"}

But now output is:

> {"name":"Name2","surname":"Surname2","gender":"m","birthDay":"20","birthMonth":"2","birthYear":"2020"}

```js
function handleFormSubmit(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            const data = new FormData(event.target);

            const formJSON = Object.fromEntries(data.entries());


            console.log(JSON.stringify(formJSON))

        }

        const form = document.querySelector('#example-form');
        form.addEventListener('submit', handleFormSubmit);
```

```html
<div class="container py-4">
        <form id="example-form">
            <div class="row">                
                    <div class="col-md-12 p-0">
                        <div class="col-md-12 form_field_outer p-0" id="app">
                            <div class="row form_field_outer_row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                    <input class="form-control w_90" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" value="" /></div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                    <input class="form-control w_90" id="surname" name="surname" placeholder="Surname" type="text" value="" /></div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                    <select class="form-control" id="gender" name="gender"><option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Gender</option>
                                        <option value="f">Female</option>
                                        <option value="m">Male</option>
                                        <option value="n">None.</option></select></div>
                                <div class="form-group col">
                                    <input class="form-control w_90" id="birthDay" maxlength="2" name="birthDay" placeholder="Day" type="text" value="" /></div>
                                <div class="form-group col">
                                    <select class="form-control" id="birthMonth" name="birthMonth">
                                        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Month</option>
                                        <option value="1">Jan</option>
                                        <option value="2">Feb</option>
                                        <option value="3">Mar</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col">
                                    <input class="form-control w_90" id="birthYear" maxlength="4" name="birthYear" placeholder="Year" type="text" value="" /></div>
                            </div>
                            <br>    
                            <div class="row form_field_outer_row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                    <input class="form-control w_90" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" value="" /></div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                    <input class="form-control w_90" id="surname" name="surname" placeholder="Surname" type="text" value="" /></div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                    <select class="form-control" id="gender" name="gender"><option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Gender</option>
                                        <option value="f">Female</option>
                                        <option value="m">Male</option>
                                        <option value="n">None.</option></select></div>
                                <div class="form-group col">
                                    <input class="form-control w_90" id="birthDay" maxlength="2" name="birthDay" placeholder="Day" type="text" value="" /></div>
                                <div class="form-group col">
                                    <select class="form-control" id="birthMonth" name="birthMonth">
                                        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Month</option>
                                        <option value="1">Jan</option>
                                        <option value="2">Feb</option>
                                        <option value="3">Mar</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col">
                                    <input class="form-control w_90" id="birthYear" maxlength="4" name="birthYear" placeholder="Year" type="text" value="" /></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="col-md ml-0 mt-3 py-3">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <button type="submit" id="submitId" class="btn btn-success float-right "><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </form>

    </div>
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: `id` should be unique across the entire document, not just the form.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have unique `id` and `name` values to your form elements.

So change the two occurences of:

```
<input id="surname" name="surname">
```

to something like this:

```
<input id="surname_0" name="person[0][surname]">
```

And the second occurence:

```
<input id="surname_1" name="person[1][surname]">
```

(I removed all other attributes to improve readability for my answer)

Comment: But I don't want to like that. I want this convert to json for a PUT method.
And the json type should be like this.  [
    {
        "name": "Name1",
        "surname": "Surname1",
        "gender": "m",
        "birthDay": 4,
        "birthMonth": 12,
        "birthYear": 1999
    },
    {
        "name": "Name2",
        "surname": "Surname",
        "gender": "f",
        "birthDay": 12,
        "birthMonth": 4,
        "birthYear": 2015
    }
]

Comment: That isn't possible without changing your HTML to something like in my answer. Otherwise, your second part of the form will override the first part. Why don't you want to change it like this?

Comment: I actually have an add button on my form that is dynamic. And when this button is clicked, the same section is added to the html file and a total of 3 sections such as name, surname, gender ... are formed. I'm thinking of sending all this data by converting it to json.

Comment: You can't have HTML elements with the same ID. And you can't have form elements with the same name. You should fix that. But if you think you've got a better idea, go ahead.

Comment: You're welcome! If that form is dynamic, please add details about it to your question. Otherwise we can't give an answer that meets your criteria.